# Ionic Angular Camera or Document Scanner file upload

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, upload

I'm having some trouble to upload images taken by Ionic Document Scanner plugin.

I get the image path and can preview it in an img tag, but I'm not being able to upload it to my Asp.Net Wep API.

When I upload a file using file input, it works perfectly. But not with scanned images or camera images.

I think the problem is that I have the local storage URL (file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1597104575209.jpg for example) but not the file itself to upload.

This is my page.ts file:

```
  scanId(){
      const opts: DocumentScannerOptions = {
          sourceType: DocumentScannerSourceType.CAMERA,
          fileName: 'docscan.jpg',
          quality: 2.5,
          returnBase64: false // get local path
      };
      this.docScanner.scanDoc(opts)
          .then((res: any) => {
            this.imagenUpload = res; // file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1597104575209.jpg
            const img = window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc( res );
            this.imagen = img;
          })
          .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
  }


  uploadImage(){
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.usuarioService.token}`
      });

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('archivo', this.imagenUpload, 'test123.jpg'); //Sending image in body with key 'archivo'

      this.httpClient.post(this._url, formData, {headers}).subscribe((res) => {
      // res contains server response
          console.log(res);
      }, err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

This is my Asp.Net api:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [Route("LicensePic")]
        public IHttpActionResult UploadLicensePic()
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["archivo"];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(
                    @"C:\Temp\RS Api",
                    fileName
                );

                file.SaveAs(path);

                var rpta = new
                {
                    status = "ok",
                    descri = "File uploaded",
                    file = file.ContentType
                };
                var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rpta);
                return ResponseMessage(result);
            }
            else
            {
                var rpta = new
                {
                    status = "error",
                    descri = "Missing file to upload"
                };
                var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, rpta);
                return ResponseMessage(result);
            }
        }
```

The response from the API is that there is no file attached to the body. Same happens if I try to upload a Camera plugin result. Only works with file input.

Can someone help me here? I'm new to Ionic so I don;t know how to handle properly Camera or Scanner results.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading image file directly, you could try getting the base64 of the file using fileSystem plugin & then sending the base64 to the server, I had tried this approach in one of my projects & it worked.